# gstreamer opencv edgedetect

Tags: ubuntu, opencv, gstreamer

I want to use edgedetect with gstreamer. I check with gst-inspect before. This is the result I have:

```
login@machine:~$ gst-inspect opencv
No such element or plugin 'opencv'
login@machine:~$ gst-inspect edgedetect
No such element or plugin 'edgedetect'
```

The installed plugin is:

```
sudo apt-cache show gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad | grep Version
Version: 1.0.3-1~ubuntu12.04.1~ppa1
Gstreamer-Version: 1.0
```

"opencv" plugin must be in plugin bad. I can launch gst-inspect with other plugins included in plugin bad, but not opencv or edgedetect.

I tried to install the plugin from the source code, nothing has changed.

Answer (score 1):

Today if you want to use the GStreamer OpenCV Plugins described [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-plugin-opencv.html) and [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/opencv/?gi-language=c) you just need to do is:

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-opencv
```

If you want to check if the `edgedetect` plugin is available (as well as the others ones):

```
$ gst-inspect-1.0 edgedetect
Factory Details:
  Rank                     none (0)
  Long-name                edgedetect
  Klass                    Filter/Effect/Video
  Description              Performs canny edge detection on videos and images.
  Author                   Michael Sheldon <mike@mikeasoft.com>

Plugin Details:
  Name                     opencv
  Description              GStreamer OpenCV Plugins
  Filename                 /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopencv.so
  Version                  1.14.5
  License                  LGPL
  Source module            gst-plugins-bad
  Source release date      2019-05-29
  Binary package           GStreamer Bad Plugins (Ubuntu)
  Origin URL               https://launchpad.net/distros/ubuntu/+source/gst-plugins-bad1.0

GObject
 +----GInitiallyUnowned
       +----GstObject
             +----GstElement
                   +----GstBaseTransform
                         +----GstVideoFilter
                               +----GstOpencvVideoFilter
                                     +----GstEdgeDetect
```

To test if it works fine:

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! edgedetect ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink
```

It worked very well on my Jetson Nano 4Gb with Jetpack 4.5.1.

For info:

```
$ dpkg -L gstreamer1.0-opencv
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0
/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstopencv.so
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/gstreamer1.0-opencv
/usr/share/doc/gstreamer1.0-opencv/AUTHORS
/usr/share/doc/gstreamer1.0-opencv/NEWS.gz
/usr/share/doc/gstreamer1.0-opencv/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/gstreamer1.0-opencv/README.gz
/usr/share/doc/gstreamer1.0-opencv/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/gstreamer1.0-opencv/copyright
```

Answer (score 0):

the opencv elements are missing from the gst-plugins-bad package in debian/ubuntu. compile it yourself and add the installation path (something like `/usr/local/lib/gstreamer-0.10`) to the searchpath of gstreamer (e.g. using the GST_PLUGIN_PATH environment variable)